# Points of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z})$ and reduction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ we have the different $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q},$ so we have $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$.

We know $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q})$ is equal to $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z})$ because in all $[a:b]$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ so we can simplify the denominators and have $a,b$ primes.

By reduction we have $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

I am very confused with the connection between all these arrows.

For example I know that the points $P$ of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z})$ are not closed in $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ so their closure contains some points of the $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

Have these points something with the reduction $\overline{P}$ of $P$? For example take $[1:1/2]=[2:1]$. This is in fact the homogeneous prime ideal $(2X-Y)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$. Its closure contains $(2X-Y,3)\in\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_3}(\mathbb{F}_3)$ but what is the link with the point $[\overline{2}:\overline{1}]\in\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_3}(\mathbb{F}_3)$?

Please help me to be less confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of this question it is probably best to think of schemes as functors.
First, let me define $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ for a ring $A$.

Say a **partial element** of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ is a tuple $(s, a_0, a_1)$ where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are elements of $A$ and $s$ is in the ideal generated by $a_0$ and $a_1$.
Say partial elements $(s, a_0, a_1)$ and $(t, b_0, b_1)$ are **compatible** if there is a natural number $r$ such that $s^r t^r a_0 b_1 = s^r t^r a_1 b_0$, i.e. if $a_0 b_1 = a_1 b_0$ in $A [s^{-1} t^{-1}]$.
For example, given a partial element $(s, a_0, a_1)$, if there exist $u, b_0, b_1$ such that $a_0 = b_0 u$, and $a_1 = b_1 u$, then $(s, a_0, a_1)$ is compatible with $(t, b_0, b_1)$ for any $t$ (in the ideal generated by $b_0$ and $b_1$).

Say a set of partial elements of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ is **consistent** if they are pairwise compatible and say the set is **total** if the first elements generate the unit ideal of $A$.
A **complete element** of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ is a set of partial elements that is consistent, total, and maximal with respect to inclusion among consistent total sets of partial elements.

Observe that if $A$ is a local ring, then any complete element of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ contains a partial element $(s, a_0, a_1)$ where $s$ is a unit (and so $a_0$ and $a_1$ generate the unit ideal of $A$).
In general, you can use the data of a complete element of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ to define a locally free submodule of $A^2$ of rank 1.
Thus, this is a generalisation of the usual definition of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ in terms of homogeneous coordinates.
However, in general, it is not possible to represent complete elements of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ by single partial elements – indeed, unlike equivalence classes, complete elements of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ may fail to be disjoint without being equal.
Then, for a ring $k$, we define $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A) = \textrm{Hom}_\textbf{CRing}(k, A) \times \mathbb{P}^1 (A)$, i.e. the set of pairs $(\alpha, E)$ where $\alpha$ is a ring homomorphism $k \to A$ and $E$ is a complete element of $\mathbb{P}^1 (A)$.
It is clear that $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A)$ is covariantly functorial in $A$ and contravariantly functorial in $k$.

Since there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to A$ for any ring $A$, the obvious natural map $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (A) \to \mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ – the one that throws away $\alpha$ – is a bijection.
Similarly, there is *at most* one ring homomorphism $k \to A$ when $k$ is any quotient of any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, so the obvious natural map $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A) \to \mathbb{P}^1 (A)$ is injective in that case.
Putting this together with the previous remark about $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$, we find that the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to k$ gives a natural injection $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A) \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (A)$ when $k$ is any quotient of any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.
(Actually, this argument shows that either $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A)$ is empty or $\mathbb{P}^1_k (A) \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (A)$ is a bijection, but let's not dwell on that.)

On the other hand, we also get natural maps $\mathbb{P}^1_k (\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{P}^1_k (A)$ for every ring $A$ and every ring $k$. Naturality means the following diagram commutes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}^1_k (\mathbb{Z}) @>>> \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbb{P}^1_k (A) @>>> \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (A)
\end{CD}$$
In the case where $k = A = \mathbb{F}_p$, the vertical maps are reduction of the coordinates modulo $p$ but the horizontal maps do not do anything to coordinates.
In fact, $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p} (\mathbb{Z})$ is empty, because there are no homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{Z}$.
On the other hand, $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p} (\mathbb{F}_p) \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a bijection – so while it is true that you can think of reduction as a map $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p} (\mathbb{F}_p)$, in some sense it is going against the grain of naturality.
Similar remarks apply when $k = A = \mathbb{Q}$, regarding the map $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q} (\mathbb{Q})$.

Now suppose $F$ is a subfunctor of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.
$F$ is closed if and only if, for every ring $A$ and every $(\alpha, E) \in \mathbb{P}^1_k (A)$, there is an ideal $I \trianglelefteq A$ such that, for every ring $B$ and every ring homomorphism $\phi : A \to B$,
$$(\phi \circ \alpha, E) \in F (B) \iff I \subseteq \ker \phi$$
We have seen that $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ is (isomorphic to) a subfunctor of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$.
It is not closed because the condition of the existence of a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to B$ is not detectable by the kernel of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to B$.
On the other hand, each $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is (isomorphic to) a closed subfunctor of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$, because the existence of a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_p \to B$ is detected by the kernel of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to B$.
The same argument shows that, for every complete element $G$ of  $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Z})$, the subfunctor $P_k$ defined by
$$P_k (B) = \{ (\beta, F) \in \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} (B) : G \subseteq F \text{ and } \exists \beta' \in \textrm{Hom}_\textbf{CRing} (k, B) \}$$
is not closed if $k = \mathbb{Q}$ and is closed if $k = \mathbb{F}_p$.
(Here, $G \subseteq F$ means, for every $(u, c_0, c_1) \in G$, we have $(u', c'_0, c'_1) \in F$, where $u', c'_0, c'_1$ are the integers $u, c_0, c_1$ considered as elements of $B$.)
You can think of $P_k$ as the part of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to $G$ considered as a $k$-valued point. The closure of $P_\mathbb{Q}$ is simply the subfunctor $P_\mathbb{Z}$, as you surmise. In particular, each $P_{\mathbb{F}_p} \subseteq P_\mathbb{Z}$, but from the functor point of view it is clearer that $P_\mathbb{Z}$ is not merely the union of $P_\mathbb{Q}$ and all the $P_{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

Comment: I'm reading your extremly detailed and interessant answer! First question: why "your" $\mathbb{P}^1_k(A)$ is "my" $\mathbb{P}^1_k(A)$? For me (if $A$ is a principal ring) $\mathbb{P}^1_k(A)$ is the set of all $\text{Spec}(A)\to\mathbb{P}^1_k$ that is the $(a_1,a_2)$ .... in fact for me $\mathbb{P}^1_k(A)=\mathbb{P}^1(A)$... I see there is a problem. Maybe $\text{Hom}(k,A)$ is here to set the structure $k$-scheme on $\text{Spec}(A)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^1_k = \operatorname{Spec}(k) \times \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$, and the functor version of $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is just $\textrm{Hom}_\textbf{CRing} (k, -)$. As you say, it is there to obtain the structure of a scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} (k)$. But if you only care about $k$-schemes for a fixed $k$ you can replace functors $\textbf{CRing} \to \textbf{Set}$ with functors $k\textbf{-Alg} \to \textbf{Set}$, and then instead of $\textrm{Hom}_\textbf{CRing}$ you use $\textrm{Hom}_{k\textbf{-Alg}}$. But $\textrm{Hom}_{k\textbf{-Alg}} (k, k)$ has only one element.

Comment: It is not clear to me why it answers my question? For example is it true that for any point $P\in\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q})$ one has that the closure of $P$ in $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ intersected with the fiber $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is the reduction of the point $P$? I think all is in your sentence "The closure of $P_\mathbb{Q}$ is simply the subfunctor $P_\mathbb{Z}$" but I'm not comfortable enough with subfunctor to see it...

Comment: Work in an affine chart, if that is easier. $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ can be covered by two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Z}$, which is representable by $\mathbb{Z} [x]$, so its closed subfunctors are classified by the ideals of $\mathbb{Z} [x]$. To find the closure of a subfunctor, you look for the largest ideal such that the corresponding closed subfunctor contains the functor you started with. Unfortunately you do have to use both affine charts to find the closure, since it is possible that either $a_0$ or $a_1$ reduces to 0.